# Chromecast Audio does not connect to 5Ghz Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, wifi-configuration, audio-streaming, chromecast

When I try to configure my Chromecast Audio (CA) using my mobile device and the Google Home app, I get the following notification:

> The Chromecast was manufactured for a different country, and may not
> be compatible with your Wi-Fi network.

When I select my 5Ghz network, at first the CA seems to be connecting to the network. However, after the configuration completes, I am not able to further configure the device via the Google Home app or cast to it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [electronics-notes.com](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/wifi-ieee-802-11/channels-frequencies-bands-bandwidth.php):

> many of the 5 GHz Wi-Fi channels fall outside the accepted ISM
> unlicensed band and as a result various restrictions are placed on
> operation at these frequencies.

[image: table with 5 GHz WiFi channels and frequencies]

**Changing the 5Ghz Wi-Fi control channel to channel 40 solved the problem for me.** Before, it was using channel 120, which seems unsupported in some regions in the world.

To change the Wi-Fi control channel, you need to log in to your Wi-Fi router’s web interface and find the Wireless settings. More information on that can be found on [this howtogeek.com article](https://www.howtogeek.com/168379/10-useful-options-you-can-configure-in-your-routers-web-interface/).